# Google Analytics: Custom UTM Parameters possible?

Tags: google-analytics

With Google Analytics, is it possible to have custom UTM parameters and map them to the original ones?

This is my URL:

```
http://some-page.com/?source=face&medium=cpc&content=ad1&term=hello&campaign=test
```

As you can see, I don't have the "utm_" in the paramters. How is it possible that GA can also track these parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the values before the pageview if the respective Url parameters exist. Mock code:

```
if(parameter medium exists) {
   ga('set', 'campaignSource', <properly escaped value of parameter>);
}
ga('send','pageview')
```

Do not simply insert an unescaped value, else you might cause security problems.

Documentation for the [various campaign fields is here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#campaignName).